# getting json data into azure pipeline

Tags: json, variables, azure-pipelines, invoke-webrequest

```
jobs:
  # Set an output variable from job A
  - job: A
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $image_infor=Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/docker-images/master/tags/sitecore-tags.json ###json data
        Write-Host $image_infor
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutput_currentDate;isoutput=true]$image_infor"
      name: setvarStep
    
  # Map the variable into job B
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables:
      myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutput_currentDate'] ]  
    steps:
    - powershell: |
          Write-Host $myVarFromJobA.Name
```

this is the issue i have been facing. The content of the variable $image_infor does not not get passed to the second job. It appears blank without an error. So when i look at the logs for job A i can actuall see the value of the $image_infor but it does not get to job B .
Any help on that please.

expecting to seet the json value in job B

Answer (score 0):

Several points need to be pay attentions.

1. setVariable should pass the **string** data type.(but yours is an object)
2. `isoutput` should be `isOutput`
3. `$myVarFromJobA.Name` should be `$(myVarFromJobA)`
4. pipeline agent has the limitate memory, so your **setVariable** size can not be too large. your json data size is too large here.

I have coded a sample with a tiny json data size.

```
jobs:
# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      $image_infor = Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/a743b015cc57a8a98d92e9c2743e52715d020258/demos/backup-la-reporting/prereqs/prereq.azuredeploy.json ###json data

      Write-Host "sample input is: $image_infor"

      $iamge_info_string = $image_infor.Content | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

      Write-Host "sample input is: $iamge_info_string"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutput_currentDate;isOutput=true]$iamge_info_string"
    name: setvarStep
  
# Map the variable into job B
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutput_currentDate'] ]
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "sample result is: $(myVarFromJobA)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you would only expect to use the **Content** of the web request to define the output variable rather than to output the **whole** `response`, please reference the sample YAML pipeline below.

```
jobs:
  # Set an output variable from job A
  - job: A
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$(sampleStorage)/sample.json
        Write-Host "================1. Web request response:================"
        $response
        
        Write-Host "================2. Convert Web request response.Content as a one-line json string:================"
        $image_infor = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress
        $image_infor

        Write-Host "================3. Set output variable myOutput_currentDate:================"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutput_currentDate;isoutput=true]$image_infor"
      name: setvarStep
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "================4. Check output variable value in the same job:================"
        Write-Host "$(setvarStep.myOutput_currentDate)"
      displayName: Check output variable value in the same job
    
  # Map the variable into job B
  - job: B
    dependsOn: A
    variables:
      myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutput_currentDate'] ]
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host myVarFromJobA: '$(myVarFromJobA)'
        $object = '$(myVarFromJobA)' | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host Ojbect: $object
        Write-Host name: $object.name
        Write-Host Array.Key6: $object.Array[1].Key6
```

[image]
[image]
In job `A`, we should first convert the json value retrived from the `.json` file to a **one-line** json string in order to pass it to downstream job; in job `B` we need to convert the output json string back to an object, so that we can extract the value referencing the object key name; in addition, we should add brackets `$( variable )` to use the output variable in script.

See for information in [Set variables in scripts - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash)